# Why do I get the "Invalid URI" error from MailChimp?

Tags: node.js, http, request, uri, mailchimp

I am trying to use the new MailChimp API v3.0 using the [request](https://github.com/request/request) module for Node.js to subscribe users from a custom form. I want to save their email address and zip code. When I try to send a POST request to `us-10.api.mailchimp.com/3.0/lists/<list-ID>/members` (where `us-10` is the datacenter ID at the end of my API key), I get an "Invalid URI" error response.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

`us-10` is not the right subdomain. Leave out the dash and that should clear right up.

Comment: Oh whoops. I typed from memory. I *do* have `us10`.

Comment: Then that's the right URI, assuming the list id is correct -- you'll want to include the actual error response you're receiving, and maybe even the code you're using to make the request.

Answer (score 0):

This **works** for me :

```
var request = require('request');
var config  = require('../config/config');

var api_key  = config.mailchimp.api_key,
    username = config.mailchimp.username,
    dc       = config.mailchimp.dc,
    list_id  = config.mailchimp.list_id;

var url = 'https://'+username+':'+api_key+'@' + dc + '.api.mailchimp.com/3.0/lists/' + list_id + '/members';

var subscribed_user = {
    email_address: 'test@node.com', // required
    status: 'subscribed'            // required 'subscribed' || 'unsubscribed' || 'pending' || 'cleaned'
};

request.post({ url: url, body: subscribed_user, json: true }, function( err, res, body ){
    if( !err )
        console.log( JSON.stringify( body, null, 4 ) );
});
```

- The auth parameters are passed according to this syntax :
  `username:password@` [RFC 1738](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc1738.txt)
- Passing `json: true` to request will internally call `JSON.stringify`on the `body` object and make sure the HTTP request is sent with the proper header `content-type: application/json`

Alternatively, you could use the `request-json` module.

Comment: I kinda moved on to using another solution for my use case. But if I find myself using MailChimp's API again, I'll probably come back to this.